# Matrices for transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

How can I find the matrices of part b and c?

[image]

the answers are:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The classical formula you might have seen in your lectures is :

$$P=B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T$$

where $B$ is the "portrait" matrix with 3 lines and $p$ columns having as its columns any basis of the d-dimensional subspace on which you project.

In case (c) for example, $p=2$:

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\
                   -1&0\\
                   0&-1\end{bmatrix} \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ B^TB=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\
                   1&2\end{bmatrix} \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ (B^TB)^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\
                   -1&2\end{bmatrix}$$

Final calculation:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\
                   -1&0\\
                   0&-1\end{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\
                   -1&2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0\\
                   1&0&-1\end{bmatrix}=\dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix}2&-1&-1\\
                   1&2&-1\\
                   -1&-1&2\end{bmatrix} $$